# SQL Server connection, session, command handling

Tags: ssas, olap, session

I am trying to build an etl tool that tracks DMV data from SSAS Instance. To do that and in advance to record sql queries that users are request, i must know how the sql server handles the connection, session and command.

For example,

- connection is created when a client app connects with ssas service with a connection string, also the connection id is different for each different user, application name, host name and start time.
- session is created when data is transferred from/to ssas service, but when a different session id is being generated for this connection?

I have noticed that some times some multiple requests uses one session, some other times requests creates different sessions.

- What makes the difference?
- Is any way to force its request create different session?
- Is any way to keep session alive in dmv storage for some specific time?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. Are you asking (a) How to change the SSAS server behavior without changing any client code? (b) how to change client tools to keep sessions open? (c) how your monitoring tool can keep its session alive? Also, are you experiencing performance issues with the connection time or something? Or are you just trying to learn?

Comment: @GregGalloway i am trying to find a way in order to capture all event sort life sessions in the dmv collector.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053833/5070440). Please let me know if that doesn't answer your question.